# Error: No events were emitted

Tags: web3js, truffle, ico, truffle-test

**I am coding an ICO project. However when trying to make the token purchase I got the following error:**

```
Using network 'test'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\DappToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\DappTokenSale.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\TRUNGL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\test--19172-maVtFUdroS6W
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Emscripten.clang


  Contract: DappToken
    ✔ initializes the contract with the correct values (74ms)
    ✔ allocates the initial supply upon deployment (41ms)
    ✔ transfers token ownership (1698ms)
    ✔ approves tokens for delegated transfer (1150ms)
    ✔ handles delegated tokens transfers (3383ms)

  Contract: DappTokenSale
    ✔ initializes the contract with the correct values (67ms)
    1) facilities token buying
    > No events were emitted


  6 passing (7s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: DappTokenSale
       facilities token buying:
     AssertionError: cannot purchased more tokens than available
      at D:\BlockChain\ICO\test\DappTokenSale.js:111:17
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

This is the file **contracts/DappTokenSale.sol**:

```
pragma solidity >0.5.0;
import "./DappToken.sol";

contract DappTokenSale {
    // Assign an admin 
    address payable admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);

    constructor (DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable{
        // Require that value is equal to tokens
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));

        // Require that contract has enough tokens
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);

        // Require that a transfer is sucessful
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        // Keep track of tokensSold
        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        // Trigger Sell event
        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }
}
```

This is the file **test/DappTokenSale.js**:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");
var DappTokenSale = artifacts.require("./DappTokenSale.sol");

contract("DappTokenSale", function (accounts) {
    var tokenInstance;
    var tokenSaleInstance;
    var admin = accounts[0];
    var buyer = accounts[1];
    var tokenPrice = 1000000000000000;
    var tokenAvailable = 750000;
    var numberOfTokens;

    it("initializes the contract with the correct values", function () {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed()
            .then(function (instance) {
                tokenSaleInstance = instance;
                return tokenSaleInstance.address;
            })
            .then(function (address) {
                assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has contract address");
                return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
            })
            .then(function (address) {
                assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has token contract address");
                return tokenSaleInstance.tokenPrice();
            })
            .then(function (price) {
                assert.equal(price, tokenPrice, "token price is correct");
            });
    });

    it("facilities token buying", function () {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed()
            .then(function (instance) {
                tokenInstance = instance;
                return DappTokenSale.deployed();
            })
            .then(function (instance) {
                // Then grab token instance
                tokenSaleInstance = instance;
                // Provision 75% of all tokens to the tokens sale
                return tokenInstance.transfer(
                    tokenSaleInstance.address,
                    tokenAvailable,
                    { from: admin }
                );
            })
            .then(function (receipt) {
                numberOfTokens = 10;
                return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, {
                    from: buyer,
                    value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice,
                });
            })
            .then(function (receipt) {
                assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, "triggers one event");
                assert.equal(
                    receipt.logs[0].event,
                    "Sell",
                    'should be "Sell" event'
                );
                assert.equal(
                    receipt.logs[0].args._buyer,
                    buyer,
                    "log the account that purchased the tokens"
                );
                assert.equal(
                    receipt.logs[0].args._amount,
                    numberOfTokens,
                    "log the number of tokens purchased"
                );
                return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
            })
            .then(function (amount) {
                assert.equal(
                    amount.toNumber(),
                    numberOfTokens,
                    "increments the number of tokens sold"
                );
                return tokenInstance.balanceOf(buyer);
            })
            .then(function (balance) {
                assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), numberOfTokens);
                return tokenInstance.balanceOf(tokenSaleInstance.address);
            })
            .then(function (balance) {
                assert.equal(
                    balance.toNumber(),
                    tokenAvailable - numberOfTokens
                );
                // Try to buy tokens different from the ether value
                return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens, {
                    from: buyer,
                    value: 1,
                });
            })
            .then(assert.fail)
            .catch(function (error) {
                assert(
                    error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0,
                    "msg.value must equal number of tokens in wei"
                );
                // Try to buy tokens different from the ether value
                return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(8000, {
                    from: buyer,
                    value: numberOfTokens * tokenPrice,
                });
            })
            .then(assert.fail)
            .catch(function (error) {
                assert(
                    error.message.indexOf("revert") >= 0,
                    "cannot purchased more tokens than available"
                );
            });
    });
});
```

**Is there any way to fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second test is using `DappTokenSale` as the token

```
it("facilities token buying", function () {
    //--------------------------
    // Should use DappToken here
    //--------------------------
    return DappToken.deployed()
        .then(function (instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return DappTokenSale.deployed();
        })
        .then(function (instance) {
            // Then grab token instance
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
```